# Почему алокация вектора занимает много времени даже с третим уровнем оптимизации?

Tags: android, c++, android-ndk

Я спрашивал подобный вопрос здесь

https://stackoverflow.com/q/58745415/5709159

вот такой код

```
#include <chrono>
#include <android/log.h>
#include <vector>

while (true)
    {
        const int sz = 2048*2048*3;
        std::vector<unsigned char> v;
        {
            auto startTime = std::chrono::system_clock::now();
            v.resize(sz);
            auto duration = std::chrono::duration_cast<std::chrono::microseconds>(std::chrono::system_clock::now() - startTime);
            __android_log_print(ANDROID_LOG_ERROR, "READFILE 1", "v.resize(%d) time : %lld\n", sz, duration.count());
        }
        {
            auto startTime = std::chrono::system_clock::now();
            v.resize(0);
            auto duration = std::chrono::duration_cast<std::chrono::microseconds>(std::chrono::system_clock::now() - startTime);
            __android_log_print(ANDROID_LOG_ERROR, "READFILE 2", "v.resize(0) time : %lld\n", duration.count());
        }
        {
            auto startTime = std::chrono::system_clock::now();
            v.resize(sz);
            auto duration = std::chrono::duration_cast<std::chrono::microseconds>(std::chrono::system_clock::now() - startTime);
            __android_log_print(ANDROID_LOG_ERROR, "READFILE 3", "v.resize(%d) time : %lld\n", sz, duration.count());
        }
    }
```

время алокации было около 500 миллисекунд

```
34.4171: v.resize(12582912) time : 845977
34.9682: v.resize(0) time : 550995
35.5293: v.resize(12582912) time : 561165
36.6121: v.resize(12582912) time : 530845
37.1612: v.resize(0) time : 548528
37.7183: v.resize(12582912) time : 556559
38.7811: v.resize(12582912) time : 515162
39.3312: v.resize(0) time : 550630
39.8883: v.resize(12582912) time : 556319
40.9711: v.resize(12582912) time : 530739
41.5182: v.resize(0) time : 546654
42.0733: v.resize(12582912) time : 554924
43.1321: v.resize(12582912) time : 511659
43.6802: v.resize(0) time : 547084
44.2373: v.resize(12582912) time : 557001
45.3201: v.resize(12582912) time : 530313
```

Но в итоге проблема оказалась в уровне оптимизации, я добавил несколько строк в `CMakeList` файл

```
target_compile_options(native-lib PRIVATE
    "$<$<CONFIG:RELEASE>:-O3>"
    "$<$<CONFIG:DEBUG>:-O3>")
```

и время снизилось до

```
E/READFILE 1: v.resize(12582912) time : 573
E/READFILE 2: v.resize(0) time : 0
E/READFILE 3: v.resize(12582912) time : 4683
E/READFILE 1: v.resize(12582912) time : 557
E/READFILE 2: v.resize(0) time : 0
E/READFILE 3: v.resize(12582912) time : 4680
E/READFILE 1: v.resize(12582912) time : 552
E/READFILE 2: v.resize(0) time : 0
E/READFILE 3: v.resize(12582912) time : 4683
```

Но я потом обратил внимание, что все равно это не логичное время, так как время первой алокации 500, потом resize на 0 занимает 0 (это так и должно быть), но время третьего resize который по своему размеру как и первый занимает 4600...

Это не возможно если знать как это работает внутри, так как единственное, что должно произойти внутири вектора это изменение одной переменной `count` с 0 на 12582912 (это тот же размер, что и в первом ресайзе), то есть не должно быть никакой алокации...

Вопрос такой - это баг в ndk vector? Или я, что то пропускаю здесь?

**P.S** я работаю с ndk android

Comment: @DrawnRaccoon `resize(0)` не производит деаллокацию, а деструктор тут тривиальный.

Comment: При resize, кроме ре-алоокоции происходит заполнение новых элементов - значением по умолчанию (нулями для char).  На это и тратися время.

Comment: @Chorkov вы про какой из трех ресайзов говорите?

Comment: Интересно. На Linux [результаты](http://coliru.stacked-crooked.com/a/dd577605e5617e68) 1 и 3 прямо противоположные. Вот [ещё](https://ideone.com/vF4lFa).

Comment: @ВЛ80 ну я работаю на андроиде с ndk, но все равно я вижу, что 3й ресайз занимает время, но этого не должно быть... Технически 2й ресайз и 3й это одно и тоже... Но второй занимает 0

Comment: Да, я вижу странность в результатах, которые вы получаете на Android, Поэтому и привёл "не-Андроид" пример, где 1 и 3 результаты противоположны вашим. _"Технически 2й ресайз и 3й это одно и тоже"_. Мне кажется, что это не совсем так. Хотя [resize()](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/container/vector/resize) и не уменьшает capacity, (не должно быть новой аллокации), но он добавляет default-inserted значения. (Как уже заметил Chorkov). **Хотя это не объясняет странность ваших результатов на Android**.

Comment: @AlekseyTimoshchenko Я говорил про самый длинный resize (от 0 до 12582912).

Comment: @Chorkov там два таких ресайза первый и третий... Про какой из них?

Comment: лично я вижу в результатах некую закономерность (ресайзы после ресайза на 0) занимают больше времени, не знаю, с чем это связано (внутренняя кухня процессора (?)), поэтому предлагаю потестить после ресайзов на 1 и вообще нужно больше тестов, по-моему.